# Error in Component class Component - inline template:7:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-testing, angular2-router

I use angular 2.1.0 modules in my current application. I get the error below if i run unit test on a component that has a routerLink attribute.

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyComponent class MyComponent - inline template:7:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyComponent class MyComponent - inline template:7:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at resolvePromise (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:429:0 <- src/test.ts:82249:31)
    at webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:465:0 <- src/test.ts:82285:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:0 <- src/test.ts:82056:37)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:96:0 <- src/test.ts:56854:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:235:0 <- src/test.ts:82055:42)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:0 <- src/test.ts:81956:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:368:0 <- src/test.ts:82188:35)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/src/app/workflow/my.component.spec.ts:131:21 <- src/test.ts:33693:22
    at TestBed.execute (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:864:0 <- src/test.ts:3973:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///home/admin1/amplifyr-web/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:951:32 <- src/test.ts:4060:49)
```

I use route params and data resolve in my component. I setup the ActivatedRouteStub and RouterStub as given in documentation. This is my TestBed config. Help me overcome the error.

beforeEach( async(() => {

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
    DummyComponent,
    RouterLinkStubDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
        [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/projects',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'projects',
            component: DummyComponent
          }

        ]
    )
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true },
    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteStub},
    {provide: Router, useValue: RouterStub}
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
    .compileComponents().then(() => {

    mockActivatedRoute = new ActivatedRouteStub();
    mockActivatedRoute.testParams = {'_id': 19}, {'ff': {'dt': { 'ns': [], 'cs': []}}, 'rs': { 'dt': []}};

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);

  // get test component from the fixture
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;

});
```

}));